# Git - clone local repository on Windows

Tags: git

I try to make a local clone of git repository on Windows. 
I typed in console:

```
cd <DEST_PATH>
git clone <SOURCE_PATH>/.git
```

and after that I get this error:

> fatal: Too many arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `SOURCE_PATH` contains spaces, which causes git to handle it as two (or more) parameters. Therefore you should quote the source path:

```
git clone "<SOURCE_PATH>/.git"
```

Depending where you execute the command (cmd.exe or Git-Bash) you may have to use slashes `/` instead of backslashes in the path.